# TypeError: takes exactly 1 argument (6 given)

Tags: python, arguments, traceback

Can't figure out why it won't allow me to pass variables into the method. The variable "module" is actually creating an object of LinkFailure:

```
from lib.remediation.link_failure import LinkFailure
from mapping import get_remediation

def remediation(dstamp,tstamp,device,error_code,error_message,ntw_device):
    module = get_remediation(error_code)
    device = module(*ntw_device)
    device.troubleshoot(dstamp,tstamp,device,error_code,error_message)
```

Here is my mapping file to get the LinkFailure:

```
######################## FUNCTIONS ##############################
from lib.remediation import link_failure 
from lib.remediation import default 

ERROR_CODES_TO_REMEDIATIONS = {
        'LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN': link_failure.LinkFailure
}

DEFAULT_REMEDIATION = {
        'default': default.Default
}

def get_remediation(error_code):

        if error_code in ERROR_CODES_TO_REMEDIATIONS:
                module = ERROR_CODES_TO_REMEDIATIONS[error_code]
        else:
                module = DEFAULT_REMEDIATION['default']

        return module
```

Here is my class file:

```
from initialize import Initialize

class LinkFailure(Initialize):

    def troubleshoot(self,dstamp,tstamp,device,error_code,error_message):
        print 'LINK FAILURE'
        print dstamp,device
```

When I run it, here is the traceback:

Why does it only allow 1 argument when I've already defined 6 including itself in the method?

```
<Thread(Thread-1, started 140335459219200)>
Sep 22 18:26:49 x.x.x.x LINK-5-CHANGED Interface GigabitEthernet1/0/12, changed state to administratively down
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/root/staging/superloopAR/parser.py", line 23, in parser
    event(dstamp,tstamp,device,error_code,error_message,ntw_device)
  File "/root/staging/superloopAR/event.py", line 9, in event
    remediation(e.datestamp,e.timestamp,e.device,e.error_code,e.error_message,ntw_device)
  File "/root/staging/superloopAR/remediation.py", line 11, in remediation
    device.troubleshoot(dstamp,tstamp,device,error_code,error_message)
TypeError: troubleshoot() takes exactly 1 argument (6 given)
```

Comment: What is the value of `device`? How many arguments does `default.Default.troubleshoot()` take?

Comment: Maybe it should be `module.troubleshoot`?

Answer (score 0):

I was checking the wrong module.. The default module with the troubleshoot method only accepted 1 argument.

I was looking at another module, link_failure and had thought it accepted 6. Human error on my side.

Comment: I didn't check the Default.troubleshoot method.. That only takes 1 argument..  Thank you sir!